# Unable to change/save any product attribute settings in admin panel

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.3

As per [this bug report](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22393), I'm having an issue where I'm unable to save any changes to product attributes in the Magento 2 admin area.

When I try to change settings of any attribute and hit save, a POST request is made to (e.g.) `https://example.com/admin/catalog/product_attribute/validate/attribute_id/200/?isAjax=true` but it receives no response.

The page then reloads to a more basic URL of `https://example.com/admin/catalog` which results in a 404 error, and the changes are not saved.

There are no errors visible.

Please note I have tried clearing (and disabling) all caches, indexes, deployed static content, checked file/folder permissions, etc. and this is still happening.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure there are no duplicate attributes, it can happen and cause this issue.

If there's a default attribute selected, try selecting a different attribute as default, and dragging it to the bottom of the sorting list and save - this actually worked for a similar issue I had. But if it doesn't save the new default or order, keep reading.

Check your `phpinfo()` `for max_input_vars`, you might need a higher number, if you have a lot of attributes. But this should be in your error logs, but can be an issue.

Try turning off your cache via CLI `bin/magento cache:disable` and see if the attributes will save with the cache off.

If still having issues, set your store to developer mode in CLI `bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer` then, run `composer update` and `bin/magento setup:upgrade`. That should update all software and modules, if they're causing the issue.

Last attempt, try running in CLI

```
composer update
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

It's less verbose, and seems to work better on some settings when other methods don't work. If you get an error about a directory not being empty when you run `bin/magento deploy:mode:set production` just try it 3 or 4 more times and it 'should' eventually run.

I hope that helps, I had a similar issue, and it deleted every swatch from my colors, and all the sizes from the admin, but not in the DB.

Comment: Thanks, increasing max_input_vars helped.